# How to capture output value of API request with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I am currently doing some basic API REST test with powershell.

However, I am having an issue with capturing a specific output data

For example:

```
$bearer = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Body $body -uri "https://api.yourwebsite.com/oauth/token"

Output:

access_token
------------
{longtokenhere}
```

But when using it with the header:

```
$header = @{Authorization = "Bearer "+$bearer}

Output is:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Authorization                  Bearer @{access_token={longtokenhere}}
```

I would like to know how will I be able to remove the " @{access_token=}" part so I can just use the {longtokehere} only?

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and it turns out I can directly call out the access_token output:

When I did this part:

```
$bearer = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Body $body -uri "https://api.yourwebsite.com/oauth/token"

Output:

access_token
------------
{longtokenhere}
```

I just simpley used this one:

```
$bearer.access_token
```

And I got the direct output of the token only:

```
{longtokenhere}
```

My final command worked with this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Header @{Authorization = "Bearer "+$bearer.access_token} -ContentType "application/json" -uri "https://api.yourwebsite.com/release/releaseID"
```